# What is the fastest way to earn money prior to the Elite 4 in Black/White 2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Traditionally, the quick way to make money in Pokémon is doing runs of the Elite 4.

In *Pokémon Black/White* and *Black/White 2*, what is the fastest way to make money before the Elite 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would probably be to re-battle trainers. You can do so at Big Stadium and Small Court in Nimbasa City once a day, or with any Pokémon Breeder, since they'll battle you each time you leave the area and they spot you/you talk to them again, as many times as you wish. Also, equip the Amulet Coin (that you can get in Castelia, according to Bulbapedia).

Answer (score 1):

In Mistralton city you can fight a trainer over and over again, and he will give you around 10000 each time. He does have 5 strong pokemon that are water types, his name is Jaun.